# How to connect Google Voice Kit to Google Actions created by the same account?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-aiy

I've connected a Google AIY Voice Kit to my laptop, creating credentials (following [this tutorial](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/#google-assistant--get-credentials)) using the same account as I used to create the google actions, I've registered my device, I'm out of ideas, the kit still doesn't recognise my actions when prompted. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you log in using the same google account? If you use the same google account all should be well. Please confirm this first.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you say something like "talk to my test app" it would invoke whatever conversational action is on the same account.

Comment: I'm logged in with the same account, and I've tried both "talk to my test app" and a custom invocation within the action. @NickFelker

Comment: Does your invocation work on your phone?

Comment: Yes, my test apps work fine on other platforms using Google Assistant. @NickFelker

Comment: Do other actions, like "talk to number genie" work? I think it should, though I am a bit stymied as to why it wouldn't work if the accounts match.